# How to make Ajax calls to Node.js api on a different port without JSONP

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a new SPA web application in order to learn Node.js.

I want to use Node.js purely as a fast API to pass JSON data to and from the server. The front-end will handle all UI/templating etc.

The issue I have is that the Node api will listen on a different port to the front-end which means cross-domain ajax calls. I don't really want to use jsonp as it's a bit of a hack and all requests would have to be GET requests. I don't want the front-end to be on the same port as the Node api either as www.mywebsite.com:9090 is not a nice web address.

Is there a common way overcoming this different port issue so that my site on port 80 can make normal json ajax requests to the Node api (which as I understand it cannot run on port 80)? It will be hosted on Azure or similar, not sure if that makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using CORS?

Comment: Thanks, CORS does what I need...except for IE9 and below. That may be my next question :)

Comment: Including the following plugin makes IE7->IE9 work: [link](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest)